# Docker-compose not building up successfully

Tags: docker-compose, docker-command, docker-cli

On running docker-compose up -d --build I am getting the following error:

`PS C:\Users\KELLYRYAN\Documents\august-code\drf_course\drf_course> docker-compose up -d --build [+] Building 128.5s (11/18)  => [api internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                             0.1s   => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s   => [api internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.1s   => => transferring dockerfile: 532B                                                                                                                                              0.0s   => [api internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10                                                                                                                2.0s   => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile_app                                                                                                                      0.1s   => => transferring dockerfile: 409B                                                                                                                                              0.0s   => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                             0.1s   => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s   => [api auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                 0.0s   => CACHED [app 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10@sha256:b24f2d9aaa0093ee4fa95a1a524badbaed4d5c7fda68ae6005b8145973183f8b                                                   0.0s   => [app internal] load build context                                                                                                                                             0.1s   => => transferring context: 31B                                                                                                                                                  0.0s   => [api internal] load build context                                                                                                                                             0.1s   => => transferring context: 2.22kB                                                                                                                                               0.0s   => CANCELED [api 2/6] RUN set -e;     apt-get update ;    apt-get -y install netcat ;    apt-get -y install gettext ;                                                          126.4s   => ERROR [app 2/5] RUN set -e;     apt-get update ;    apt-get -y install netcat ;    apt-get -y install gettext ;    apt-get -y  install httpie;     pip install --upgrade p  126.2s  ------`

`failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c set -e;     apt-get update ;    apt-get -y install netcat ;    apt-get -y install gettext ;    apt-get -y  install httpie;     pip install --upgrade pip     pip install flask" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100`

I am using windows 10. And I have tried restarting docker a couple of times and rerunning the command but nothing seems to change.

My file structure looks like this
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baX3o.png)

What could be the problem as I cannot find links to solve this for windows?

Answer (score 0):

I think a ";" is missing between `pip install --upgrade pip` and `pip install flask`

Comment: I hadn't seen that. Thank you. Where should I edit that because that's a snippet of the error.

Comment: I found it and added the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with netcat as well as a missing semicolon as explained above by @chc.

This can be fixed by editing the
(1) Dockerfile from this:

```
RUN set -e; \
apt-get update ;\
apt-get -y install netcat ;\ 
apt-get -y install gettext ;

RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code

RUN set -e; \
/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip ;\
python -m pip install -r /code/requirements.txt ;\
chmod +x /code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh ;

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh"]
```

to this:

```
RUN set -e; \
apt-get update ;\
apt-get -y install netcat-traditional;\ 
apt-get -y install gettext ;
```

(2)and the Dockerfile_app, from this:

```
RUN set -e; \
apt-get update ;\
apt-get -y install netcat ;\
apt-get -y install gettext ;\
apt-get -y  install httpie; \
pip install --upgrade pip \
pip install flask
```

to this:

```
RUN set -e; \
apt-get update ;\
apt-get -y install netcat-traditional ;\
apt-get -y install gettext ;\
apt-get -y  install httpie; \
pip install --upgrade pip; \
pip install flask
```

Run the command docker-compose up -d --build successfully.